# Trying to get my email form to validate before sending

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have the html here where I import the javascript code into to validate the form fields contain info before being sent. I looked at some of the other answers and tried different solutions but I can't seem to fix it. There is also PHP code that's supposed to get the input from the text fields and send them to my email. That works fine except the validation process from the JS code is not working and thus emails can be sent without typing anything in the forms.

Now to explain what I tried was basically adding class #id to button and then calling it

```html
 <script src="js/contact.js"></script>

 <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="emailAddress">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'" placeholder = 'Enter Message'></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder = 'Enter your name'>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder = 'Enter email address'>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder = 'Enter Subject'>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <button type="button" class="button button-contactForm btn_4 boxed-btn" id="PleaseWork" onClick="">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

contact.js code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function($) {
        "use strict";


    jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
    }, "type the correct answer -_-");

    // validate contactForm form
    $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                number: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "come on, you have a name, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "come on, you have a subject, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your subject must consist of at least 4 characters"
                },
                number: {
                    required: "come on, you have a number, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your Number must consist of at least 5 characters"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "no email, no message"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
                    minlength: "thats all? really?"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    url:"contact_process.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                            $('#success').fadeIn()
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                            $('#success').modal('show');
                        })
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $('#error').fadeIn()
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                            $('#error').modal('show');
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })

 })(jQuery)
})
```

contact_process.php

```php
<?php

    $to = "Myemail@email.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    //$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "You have a message from your Bitmap Photography.";

    $logo = 'img/logo.png';
    $link = '#';

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
    $body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
    $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
    $body .= "</tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$subject}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    //echo("Email was sent successfully");

?>
```

Comment: I'm also kind of new to this so take it easy on me. I want to be guided on how to solve this so I can learn from it.

Comment: Were you able to get this worked out?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the **jQuery Validation Plugin**. Are you linking to the plugin? There typically would be something like this in the page's `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate both using Javascript and PHP with plugin or without plugin

Watch this: [PHP Contact form with jQuery Validation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7lnU8hJRjo)